# Creating a circle with grass around it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, patterns, texture

Using Photoshop CS6.
I'm currently trying to make a circle with grass around it. Think a 2D world with dirt in the middle and grass on the sides.
Currently im trying to do it with minecraft textures since they seem almost perfect for this, so you get an idea what I mean:
[image: grass]

Now this, just around a circle, sorta like this:
[image: circle]

The problem is I haven't found a way to make a pattern follow a shape yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy job in Adobe Illustrator.

At first your texture image was taken into a photo editor (=Photoshop) A soil-only version was generated by copying the brown soil texture over the grass. After that we have two texture photos - the original and the soil-only version

Both of the texture images was traced to 2 pixel accurate vector images with 64 colors

The vectorized original was dragged to Brushes panel to make a new pattern brush

The vectorized soil-only image was dragged into the Swatches panel to complete the swatches collection

A curve was drawn by a new brush. No fill was used because the new soil swatch makes an observable border with the soil in the stroke due the different fine structures

A copy of the curve was made with a little reduced size. That had no stroke, but the soil fill.

The soil filled shape was slightly blurred Effect > Blur > Gaussian Blur

[image]

This could be developed by making a grass only fill swatch and maybe a grass only Brush, too.

Illustrator is not a must. The same job is possible in Photoshop, but differently. In Photoshop the Pattern Stamp can paint the grass and the soil. Unfortunately there's no easy way to turn the stamp pattern as you go along the wanted path. That's no problem if the pattern is solidly filled. This is NOT the case when painting the ragged edge of the grass. 2 workarounds are easy:

- draw a straight line, a grass belt and bend it by Filter > Liquify
- draw the grass with solid edge and add the ragged edge afterwards by cloning or drawing by hand

In the following example the bending is used. The small windows are the used stamp patterns (= Edit > Define Pattern). Actually the upper and lower halves of the grass belt are drawn and bent separately to reduce the bending.

[image]